Input size in tensorflow build
I am looking at the example from the documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


class Autoencoder(Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim, shape):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.shape = shape
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Flatten(),  # flattens input WITHOUT affecting batch size
      layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
    ])
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(tf.math.reduce_prod(shape).numpy(),
                   activation='sigmoid'),
      layers.Reshape(shape)
    ])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded


# (x_train, _), (x_test, _) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

print(x_train.shape)  # (60000, 28, 28)
print(x_test.shape)   # (10000, 28, 28)

shape = x_test.shape[1:]
latent_dim = 64
autoencoder = Autoencoder(latent_dim, shape)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.MeanSquaredError())
# autoencoder.build(input_shape=x_train.shape)  # nope
# autoencoder.build(input_shape=(None, 28, 28))  # nope
# autoencoder.summary()

I would like to build the model to get a summary. What should the input_shape be? Inputs will be images of size 28x28.
I would have expected this to work:
autoencoder.build(input_shape=(None, 28, 28))

Thank you very much!

Input size is almost always without the batch dim. Try (28, 28, 1) for binary images and (28, 28, 3) for rgb images. Also a tip for next time, please write what happened when you tried your approach instead of just "expected this to work".

Thank you for the suggestion.
Upon revisiting the example:
autoencoder.build(input_shape=x_train.shape)
autoencoder.summary()

yields:
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 sequential (Sequential)     (60000, 64)               50240     
                                                                 
 sequential_1 (Sequential)   (60000, 28, 28)           50960     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 101,200

The following:
autoencoder.build(input_shape=(None, 28, 28))
autoencoder.summary()

yields:
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 sequential_2 (Sequential)   (None, 64)                50240     
                                                                 
 sequential_3 (Sequential)   (None, 28, 28)            50960     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 101,200
Trainable params: 101,200
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

In both cases the number of parameters for the first layer are 28 x 28 x 64 + 64 = 50240, as expected.
Thanks for the hint!
